# Read files asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to read some files and store their name in an array in nodejs. I have made a function. It reads the file, and prints them out in the console, but the output of the array is []. I am assuming it is because node.js is asynchronous, but I thought a callback would fix it?

```js
readCurdir("./uploads/", curDirReadFinn); 
function readCurdir(dir, callback){
  var tmpArray = []; 
  fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files){
    if(err){
      if(err.code==='EISDIR'){}
      else{
        console.log(err);
      }
      return; 
    }
    files.forEach(function(file){
      fs.readFile(dir + file, 'utf-8', function(err, data){
        if(err){
          if(err.code==='EISDIR'){}
          else{
            console.log(err);
          }
          return; 
        }
        tmpArray.push(file); 
        console.log(file);   //this prints
      }); 
    }); 
  }); 
  callback(tmpArray); 
} 
function curDirReadFinn(array){ 
    console.log(array); //Output: []
}
```

I have also tried this:

```js
files.forEach(function(file){
  fs.readFile(dir + file, 'utf-8', function(err, data){
    if(err){
      if(err.code==='EISDIR'){}
      else{
        console.log(err);
      }
      return; 
    }
    tmpArray.push(file); 
    counter++; 
    if(counter === files.lenght){
    callback(tmpArray); 
    }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: You should probably do `tmpArray.push(data);` Right now you are just  storing file references.

Comment: Yes i am storing the filenames , that is the point. The reason i am reading the file(fs.readFile) is because i want to filter out the folders.

Comment: then reading all the files is a bit overkill, you can fetch the [stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) and [check wether it isFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats), without reading all the data from the filesystem

Comment: Oh ok, thanks! You are right, loading all the data from the files is a bit of a waste when i only want the file names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea with your second attempt.
After I'd simplified it, it then works perfectly:

```
function readCurdir(dir, callback){
  var tmpArray = []; 

  fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }

    var counter = files.length;

    files.forEach(function(file) {
      fs.stat(path.join(dir, file), function(err, stats) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        else if (stats.isFile()) {
          tmpArray.push(file); 
        }

        --counter === 0 && callback(tmpArray);
      }); 
    });
  }); 
}
```

You can simplify it even further (and propagate errors more easily) using the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module:

```
async.each(files, function(file, cb) {
  fs.stat(path.join(dir, file), function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
      return cb(err);
    }
    else if (stats.isFile()) {
      tmpArray.push(file); 
    }

    cb();
  }); 
}, function(err) {
    callback(err, tmpArray)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous code strikes again! `fs.readdir()` is asynchronous. Your `callback` method is called separate from the execution of `fs.readdir()`. That's why your `tmpArray` is empty when you log it in your callback method `curDirReadFinn()`.

There are some ways to fix your problem:

1. Ready your directory and files synchronously. NodeJS has methods for that. See here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options
2. As @Thomas mentioned, you can make use of `stat` and `isFile()` to get it over with faster. In general eliminate the need for heavy asynchronous code.
3. Use Promises!

Comment: Yepp, just started using promises. Thanks!